# BeautifulSoup: NoneType error when parsing a HTML file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My script is written below and found an error for `soup.get_text()` command.
Code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
soup=BeautifulSoup(open("F:\\HTML\\Registrationform.html"))
print soup.get_text('+')
```

Error:   File "`C:/Python27/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.tar/scrapingbasic.py`", line 3, in

```
 print soup.get_text('+')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: update to [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 1):

`BeautifulSoup` class expects `html`/`xml` contents in the constructor. SO adding `.read()` to your `open` function should work.
Here's the code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
soup=BeautifulSoup(open("F:\\HTML\\Registrationform.html").read())

print soup.get_text('+')
```

Also, I would recommend you to upgrade to `BeautifulSoup4`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Beautifulsoup expects html/xml document. Can you please check if python 2.x can parse your html file, just for recheck. Another issue may happen on windows, need to make sure that lxml library installed successfully. Also you can recheck the documentation from: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

with the following section:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("index.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
```

Comment: Run successfully print soup.get_text('+').
Thanks you all.